# groupby select value only if match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I got my data sorted correctly, but now Im trying to find a way to group by "first not empty string value". Is there a way to do this without changing the rest of the data? First was close, but not quite what I needed

```
grouped = sortedvals.groupby(['name']).first().reset_index()
```

doesnt work if the first value is empty ie: `'',2` (my goal is to return 2) but does work for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `replace` function to replace blank values with `np.nan`

```
import numpy as np

grouped = sortedvals.replace('',np.nan).groupby(['name']).first().reset_index()
```

Comment: @Prateek yep, import numpy as np